# ForLoop Continuously Looping inside Override Method Android

Tags: java, android, for-loop, arraylist

I have an **Interface** which methods are implementing in other classes.
Inside that method i am having **forLoop** to check if item already exists in particular List but that **ForLoop** calling continuously.
Here is my Code:

```
@Override
public void saveResultList(MyOrderResultPOJO myOrderResultPOJO) {

    myOrderResultList.add(myOrderResultPOJO);


    checkItemId(myOrderResultPOJO);

    //myOrderResultHashMap.put(inventoryClassificationId, myOrderResultList);
    setMyOrderResultListNew(myOrderResultList);
}

private boolean checkItemId(MyOrderResultPOJO myOrderResultPOJO){
    boolean v=false;

    for (int i=0;i<myOrderResultList.size();i++) {

        if (myOrderResultList.get(i).getItemId().equals(myOrderResultPOJO.getItemId())) {
            myOrderResultList.add(i,myOrderResultPOJO);
            Log.d("myOrderResultList","entering");
            v=true;
        }
    }

    return v;

}
```

**Interface:**

```
public interface MyOrderSubList {
    void addMtPcsSpinner(Context ctx, Spinner spinner);

    void showMessages(String message);

    void hideKeyBoards();

    void saveResultList(MyOrderResultPOJO myOrderResultPOJO);
}
```

Comment: Add a break inside if to stop the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just return `true` if you find a match. You definitely don't want to add the existing element to the `List` again (`myOrderResultList.add(i,myOrderResultPOJO);` is the cause of the infinite loop).

```
private boolean checkItemId(MyOrderResultPOJO myOrderResultPOJO)
{
    for (int i=0;i<myOrderResultList.size();i++) {
        if (myOrderResultList.get(i).getItemId().equals(myOrderResultPOJO.getItemId())) {
            Log.d("myOrderResultList","entering");
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;    
}
```

That said, the logic of the caller method (`saveResultList`) is strange. First you add the element to the `List`, and later you call `checkItemId(myOrderResultPOJO)`, which checks if it exists in the `List` (and you ignore the value returned by that method). It should probably be the other way around:

```
public void saveResultList(MyOrderResultPOJO myOrderResultPOJO) 
{
    if (!checkItemId(myOrderResultPOJO)) {
        myOrderResultList.add(myOrderResultPOJO);
    }

    setMyOrderResultListNew(myOrderResultList);
}
```

Comment: i want to update arraylist element  if element is exists.

Comment: @SivabalanD If you want to update an existing element, use `myOrderResultList.set(i,myOrderResultPOJO)` instead of `myOrderResultList.add(i,myOrderResultPOJO)`.

Answer (score 0):

You're ending up adding to the `size` of the list which is what thc condition of your `for` loop is `i<myOrderResultList.size()` :

```
myOrderResultList.add(i,myOrderResultPOJO); // not required
```

So you can update it to

```
for (int i = 0; i < myOrderResultList.size(); i++) {
    if (myOrderResultList.get(i).getItemId().equals(myOrderResultPOJO.getItemId())) {
        Log.d("myOrderResultList", "entering");
        v = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: but i want to update the arraylist if element is exists.

Comment: @SivabalanD yes, in which case the suggestion by Eran could further help you. You are adding to the list currently with your solution which should ideally be conditional based on the return type of your `checkItemId` method.